# Scroller in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a table layout panel that in each row i have a Label that give to the user details.
If the label is "very long" some of the text of the label gets lost. So I thought of adding a scroller to scroll down on each cell of the table layout.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TableLayoutPanel does not support individual cells with a scrollbar nor does the label control have scrollbar abilities.

You can try using a TextBox instead with `Multiline=True`, `ReadOnly=True` and `ScrollBars=Vertical`.